# How to change projectile-bookmarks.eld saving path?

Tags: projectile, bookmarks

`emacs` keeps generating file called `projectile-bookmarks.eld` in home directory.

How could I make it to save that file under `~/.emacs.d/tmp` or a different path?

---

I also keep seeing `Reverting buffer ‘projectile-bookmarks.eld’.` whenever I open a new buffer.

---

As solution I have been [told that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27658379/2402577):

> you can modify the variable projectile-known-projects-file

I have done: `(setq projectile-known-projects-file "~/.emacs.d/tmp/projectile-bookmarks.eld")`

Now the file is generated under `~/` and `~/.emacs.d/tmp/`. How can I prevent it to saved under the home directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the following variables.

```
(setq projectile-cache-file (expand-file-name "projectile.cache" 
                             user-emacs-directory)
      projectile-known-projects-file (expand-file-name "projectile-known-projects.eld"
                             user-emacs-directory))
```

You can customize your desired name and path in the above snippet. Note that I have also included a second variable that controls another temporary file created by `projectile`.

Another nice way to keep your `.emacs.d` clean is to use the `no-littering` package.

```
(use-package no-littering
   :ensure t)
```

You can look up the description of the `no-littering` package [here](https://github.com/emacscollective/no-littering).

Comment: I have added the code piece you shared to my init.el file but it still generated the file under home directory. Should I do anything else?

Comment: Can you share the related configuration? Maybe try setting the variables before loading `projectile`?